# Rails server not staring - There was an error while trying to load the gem 'omniauth-linkedin' in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, omniauth-linkedin

I'm absolutely new to ruby on rails application. I'm stuck with an error while starting the rails server, it shows:

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem omniauth-linkedin. (Bundler::GemRequireError).
```

Following are the version that I'm using:

- ruby 2.1.8
- Rails 4.0.13
- omniauth-linkedin (0.2.0)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting while loading `gem omniauth-linkedin`

Answer (score 0):

I think that gem is not working anymore, prolly you'll want to use:

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

Comment: I tried installing `gem omniauth-linkedin` and it works.